# Appending to list of lists randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an initial list, comprising 1000 lists, some empty and some not. I'm trying to disperse 2000 floats amongst those empty lists at random(empty_list45, empty_list2, ..., empty_randn), not in order (empty_list1, empty_list1, ..., empty_listn).

Here's my attempt:

```
#the list containing lists.
folder = [[]] * 1000
for i in range(len(newOPsys_i)):
    folder[newOPsys_i[i]] = (newOP[i])

#list of indices of empty lists in folder, where folder is the list comprising 1000 lists that may or may not be empty 
empty = []
for i in range(len(folder)):
    if not folder[i]:
        empty.append(i)

#function that pulls a random index from any called list
def rand(mylist):
rando = random.randint(0,len(mylist)-1)
return(rando)

#my attempt at appending 2000 floats to random empty lists in folder
for i in range(0,2000):
    x = empty[rand(empty)]
    print(folder[x])
    folder[x].append(match[x][random.randint(0,len(match[x])-1)]) #match is a separate list where I wish to pull the floats from, and place them into the empty lists.
```

My output looks something like:

```
[]
[3.9]
[3.9, 7.8]
[3.9, 7.8, 54.9]
```

From the print, what seems to be happening instead is that in the first iteration an empty list is found then a single float is appended. On the next iteration, another empty list is randomly found, but appended to this empty list is the float from the last iteration, along with a new float. This is not what I want to happen, I just want those single random floats appended each iteration. Any insights? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to append your 2000 floats at random to a list chosen randomly?

Comment: @sauravverma no, I want to disperse the 2000 floats amongst randomly chosen empty lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import random
 f = [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8], [10, 67, 89], [34, 54, 32, 76], [24, 90, 9, 4, 2]]
 for _float in <2000 floats>:
     integer = random.randint(0, len(f)-1) #this will shuffle your list of lists 
     f[integer].append(_float)
```

Since you are shuffling your list, the last list will be random and you can append your float to the last list or any other index for that matter.

Comment: OUCH. You are shuffling 1000 inner lists 2000 times to put 1 float in it? Why not use a `random.randint(0,999)` to simply randomize which list to use and then `allLists[randomIndex].append(_one_float_)`  that would be a couple thousand times more effective